# Pully size, imagine 2 systems A,B both transmitting power, both 1:1 but if OD of pulley is 50mm on A and 100mm on B, How do we choose optimal size?

Tags: applied-mechanics

All searches resulted in ratio calculations, which makes sense, my question relates to creating a servo driven spindle with 1:1 ratio with timing belt. Is increased belt surface engagement important since its a toothed belt? Also system A and B are examples only.

Comment: How much power? That drives the size of the belt and therefore its smallest pulley size. Check out belt manufacturers - plenty of info easily available.

Comment: Whatever is the cheapest